# Dictionary Comprehension to generate values of built-in type

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I would like to do a dictionary comprehension to get a list of keys with the built-in type of `str` as values.

```
headers = ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3']
print dict([(x,str) for x in headers])
```

output:

```
{'Header2': <type 'str'>, 'Header3': <type 'str'>, 'Header1': <type 'str'>}
```

Desired output:

```
{'Header2': str, 'Header3': str, 'Header1': str}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **do** have a dictionary with the built-in `str` in it.

The `<type 'str'>` is due to the `print` call which will use the value obtained from calling an objects' `__str__` when it prints it. That value for `str` is `<type 'str'>`.

If you save the dictionary, access one of the members and use it you'll see it **is** the `str` class:

```
>>> d = dict([(x,str) for x in headers])
>>> d['Header1'](123)
'123'
```